# How to access controller methods from other controller files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

When I try to access the `index`, `new`, `edit` methods/actions defined in the controller in the other spec files outside controller folder, it is throwing this error

> Rails::RSpec::CoreExampleGroup- NoMethodError

Comment: Are you writing a unit test or an integration test? If this is a unit test for a controller, you shouldn't need to access another controller. If it's an integration test, you shouldn't need to invoke methods from your controller at all.

Comment: @alfonso - I am writing performance tests and i need to access   methods from different controllers

Answer (score 1):

Now you can access the controller methods in any spec files by adding this

`include RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup`

at the top of the spec file.